# printing a palindrome diamond in c

Tags: c

im trying to generate a palindrome diamond according to the user's input. For example, if user input = 3, the generated pattern would be:

```
  1
 121
12321
 121
  1
```

however, my current code is generating this:

```
  1
 121
12321
 1234321
  123454321
```

I have an inkling as to what went wrong but i have ran out of ideas on how to change it. Can anyone provide some insights please

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int n, i, j;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int rows = n*2-1;
    int spaces = n-1;

    for(i=1; i<=rows; i++) {
        for(j=1; j<=spaces; j++) 
            printf(" ");

        for (j=1; j<=i; j++) 
            printf("%d", j);

        for (j=i-1; j>=1; j--) 
            printf("%d", j);
        
        if (i<n) {
            spaces--;
        } else {
            spaces++;
        }

        printf("\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use two loops, one that handles the first `n` lines, and another that handles the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mistake:**

You are performing correct operations for the first lines but then you are continuing the same thing (for the next part of the structure) instead of reversing the logic for the next part.

**Logic:**

So for that use one for loop for the first part and use another for loop for the second part of the structure.

**Code:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n = 0, i = 0, j = 0;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int rows = n, spaces = n - 1;

    for(i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for(j = 1; j <= spaces; j++) 
            printf(" ");

        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
            printf("%d", j);

        for (j = i - 1; j >= 1; j--) 
            printf("%d", j);

        spaces--;

        printf("\n");

    }

    spaces = 1;
    for(i = rows - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
        for(j = 1; j <= spaces; j++) 
            printf(" ");

        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
            printf("%d", j);

        for (j = i - 1; j >= 1; j--) 
            printf("%d", j);

        spaces++;

        printf("\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```